# when is an iterator implementation a better practice than indexing?

Tags: iterator

When is an iterator implementation a better practice than offering indexing?  When it is better, why?

I am assuming that I am the implementer of a class that can offer either and a choice needs to be made.

Answer (score 1):

Because most collections are iterable, but few collections are indexable (e.g. hashtables).

Using iterators allows you to create code that doesn't care about the type of each collection.

Comment: May be it's expensive but can I not sort map keys and hash keys and index them?  I was thinking iterators are an encapsulation practice and I am not used to thinking of iterators as a necessity due to expense (time).

Comment: @broiyan: The **container** isn't indexable (not in any sensible way, anyway). You could retrieve them and index them yourself, but that has nothing to do with the container...

Comment: I meant if I am the implementer of the container.

Comment: @broiyan: How would you index a hashtable and still be able to add items to it?

Comment: May be just add to the hash table.  Then after each add build/rebuild a contiguous integer index in a separate object like a list.

Comment: @broiyan: Wouldn't that completely defeat the purpose of a hashtable (i.e. performance)?

Comment: @ mehrdad  If something is silly for performance reasons or whatever reason, then choosing between an iterator and indexing is not an issue. This question is about when the choice is not obvious. If hash tables are not indexable, then there is no choice to be made. This question is about cases when a choice is possible. Is your answer supposed to hint at upcasting?  I want to choose an answer but unfortunately I do not understand yours well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation: with an iterator you do not have to know what the valid indices are.